# Unable to create process using 'C:\bin\env python3 "C:\Users\frtb\TelegramScraper\scraper.py" ': Access is denied

Tags: python

How can I fix this error I've tried almost everything
Python 3.10

Setting path, running admin, i've tried looking it up to no results

Please let me know a solution to this problem I've been trying to get this working for a while now without success.

Comment: Share more information like code and error message